# Sumif with mapping multiple the same rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to write excel formula that will sumif the values based on a match of the rows. The problem is that I the cells to be matched can occur multiple times and basing on the Mapping legend they should return the sum of values.

In the yellow cells I am trying to caluclate sumif of values in range B9:B14. In formula I am using index to match the names and to return the sum of all that is assined to Item1, then Item2 and Item 3. Unfortunately, Index gives only the match with the first met not with the all that I have in mapping legend. Does Anybody has idea how to write this formula?

Here is the formula that I use (wrong) and in cell C4 and C5  is the result that should be achieved for Item 2 and Item 3:

[image]:

Item 1 is ok because it does not have more than 1 mapping.

Comment: B10 to B15 maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the following in B3 and drag down.

Enter as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$10:$A$15=IF($F$3:$F$8=$A3,$G$3:$G$8)),$B$10:$B$15)
```

[image]

This works because the arrays are of equal length and items appear in the same order.

Comment: That's definitely what I was looking for! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Hi QHarr, do you have maybe a solution how to change this formula if I want to extend Input sum array leaving the mapping legend of the same size? Or should I post it as separate question?

Comment: Can you post as new with example info showing what you want to achieve? It is easier than trying to work it out in the comments plus you may get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily accomplish this in two steps:

1. In H3 enter formula: `=SUMIF($A$10:$B$15, G3, $B$10:$B$15)`. Drag it all the way down until 8th row.
2. In B3 enter formula: `=SUMIF($F$3:$H$8, A3, $H$3:$H$8)`. Drag it all the way down until 5th row.

Your results should be like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Michal, I know that it is achievable when splitting the formula in 2 steps or even other ways. But I am wondering how to do it in one formula because the Mapping legend is going to be in the other sheet and should not be bothered by any values around.

Answer (score 0):

its very simple no need to complicate with index functions.

First you need to cross ref the mapping legend with your inputs using sum-if function and then do that again to get individual values from each items.

[Sumif in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCerZ.png)

[Sumif visualized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4itn.png)

With refrence to the image put this formula in H3 to H8

```
=SUMIF($A$10:$A$15,G3,$B$10)
```

and then this formula in B3 to B5

```
=SUMIF($F$3:$F$8,A3,$H$3:$H$8)
```